# SwiftUI Preview is not working with Error message

Tags: error-handling, swiftui, preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFwuH.jpg)

Hi, check the attached picture, please.

I can't use preview with SwiftUI with that error message.

Can anyone help me to use that?

Comment: Please include the code (not an image of it) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If "Try Again" doesn't work, there is usually some error that is not being caught by the compiler. Run it on the simulator and see where it crashes...